# ¿como insertar mi arreglo de String de mi clase hija?

Tags: java

Necesito ayuda para poder insertar mi arreglo de `String empresas`, el cual lleva el nombre de empresas de un proyecto de un aeropuerto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que al momento de agregar mi arreglo de empleados

```
   switch (tipo) {
   case 1: for(int i=0; i<numMaxEmpresas;i++){
           System.out.print("Digite su nombre: ");
           in.nextLine();
           empresas[i] = in.nextLine();
          }
                   
       ((AeropuertoPrivado)aeropuertos[h]).insertarEmpresa(empresas[i]);
                aeropuertos[h] = new AeropuertoPrivado(nombreAeropuerto, ciudadAeropuerto,paisAeropuerto);
                break;
       }
```

Me lanza el siguiente error:

> Digite el tipo de aeropuerto, privado = 1, publico = 2: 1
> Digite su nombre: Aviones
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
> at proyecto.Principal.insertarAeropuerto(Principal.java:195)
> at proyecto.Principal.menu1(Principal.java:161)
> at proyecto.Principal.main(Principal.java:129)
> PS C:\Users\emmanuel\Desktop\Curso java VS\10.-Bloque_10 Proyecto v3>

Ya lo he intentado con el buffer y el downcasting pero nada.

Comment: Yo creo que aeropuertos[h] es nulo y no lo puedes asignar, pero no te puedo decir más sin ver cómo creas el array de aeropuertos

Comment: luego de in.nextLine(); estas cerrando la llave del for } extiendolo hasta después de break; ahora que valor tiene h ???

Answer (score 1):

Creo que tienes varios errores, uno es la forma del switch que no sigue la sintaxis de este mismo.

```
    int opcion=2;

    switch (opcion){
        case 1:{
            System.out.println("Usted eligió la opcion 1.");
            break;
        }

        case 2:{
            System.out.println("Usted eligió la opcion 2.");
            break;
        }

        default: {
            System.out.println("Opcion incorrecta");
        }

  }//cierra SWITCH
```

Por otro lado, que creo que es el error que te debe estar dando, cuando usas la función `.insertarEmpresa()` debes haber construido antes el objeto y lo estas haciendo al revés.

```
aeropuertos[h] = new AeropuertoPrivado(nombreAeropuerto, ciudadAeropuerto,paisAeropuerto);
((AeropuertoPrivado)aeropuertos[h]).insertarEmpresa(empresas[i]);
```

También debes asegurarte que tanto el arreglo `empresas` como el arreglo `aeropuertos` tengan los tamaños que estas utilizando.

También utilizas 2 veces(una sin asignar) `in.nextLine()`.

Creo que tu código correcto debería ser así:

```
    switch (tipo) {
        case 1:{
 for(int i=0; i<numMaxEmpresas;i++){
            System.out.print("Digite su nombre: ");
            empresas[i] = in.nextLine();
}
            
            aeropuertos[h] = new AeropuertoPrivado(nombreAeropuerto, ciudadAeropuerto, paisAeropuerto);
     
     
  ((AeropuertoPrivado)aeropuertos[h]).insertarEmpresa(empresas[i]);
            break;
        }
       //Resto del switch         
       }
```